# TcpClient C# Windows Form como fechar e abrir a mesma conexão

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Windows Form C# e estou usando TcpClient para realizar comunicação dentro da minha rede interna, em alguns momentos necessito fechar uma conexão existente e após alguns minutos reabrir esta conexão, mas estou tendo problemas ao realizar este procedimento.

Primeiramente inicializo o TcpClient.

```
TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
clientSocket.Connect(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
```

Em determinado momento desejo fechar esta conexão, tentei o Dispose() e Close().

```
clientSocket.Dispose();
clientSocket.Close();
```

E depois desejo em um momento reconectar realizando o seguintes comandos

```
 if (!clientSocket.Connected)//Verifico se a conexão esta ativa
 {
      clientSocket = new TcpClient();//Estáncio novamente clientSocket
      clientSocket.Connect(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text));//Mas dá exceção nesta linha.
 }
```

Com todos procedimentos adotados acima é retornado um Exception

**System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Uma operação de soquete foi tentada em um host inacessível xx.xx.x.xx:8080'**, na linha abaixo

```
clientSocket.Connect(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
```

Isto quer dizer que a conexão realmente fica instanciada não deixando realiza uma nova conexão.

Como realizar este procedimento, para que tenha a liberdade de realizar estes procedimentos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é devido a não ter correctamente desconectado a conexão anterior e fazer uma nova ligação usando a mesma porta.

Para fechar a conexão use

```
NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream();
stream.close();
clientSocket.close();
```

Quando quiser conectar novamente crie uma nova instância e use o `Connect(....)` dessa instância.